# Calculating Times with a Loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has multiple patient records for the same patients with the first two columns being their visit times, the next two columns being what stage of their disease they are in when they visited, and the next two columns corresponding with what treatment they are on. I want to calculate the start and end time of each patient based on the first treatment they were given at visit 1. I was able to figure out the start time based on a solution in another post but am struggling with finding a end time.

I have tried different solutions that were given to me on here but I seem to keep running into issues with it giving me the correct end time when I run it with my original dataset. I think the best method for finding the end time has to be a loop because it will go through the each row for each unique patient and flag the conditions I need it to.

The conditions I want in the loop:
If the patient has a start time to go to the next row and if R2 is "Death" then check to make sure that T1 equals the firstTrt and then break and record V2. If R2 is "Response" then to go through each of the rows to check if the treatments (T1 and T2) equal the firstTrt and if R2 changes to "Disease" or the treatments change to break and record the time (V2). There are records from the same patient where they stay on a the first treatment switch and then go back I only want the time before they switch.

Here is a reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(
  Patient = c('Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', "Dave",'Dave', "Angel", "Angel", "Angel", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Cara", "Cara", "Tanya", "Tanya", "Tanya", "Tanya"),
  V1 = c(1, 92, 714,917,986,1, 150, 375, 1, 150, 375, 1, 150, 1,150, 375,568),
  V2 = c(92, 714,917,986,988,150, 375, 568, 150, 375, 568, 150,375, 150, 375, 568, 600),
  R1 = c("Disease","Response","Disease","Response", "Response", "Disease","Disease", "Response","Disease", "Response", "Response", "Disease", "Response", "Disease", "Response", "Response", "Disease"),
  R2 = c("Response", "Disease", "Response","Response", "Response" ,"Disease", "Response", "Death", "Response", "Disease", "Response", "Response", "Death", "Response", "Response", "Disease", "Response"),
  T1 = c("A","A","A","A","B" ,   "A","B","B", "A","A","C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A","B" ),
  T2 = c("A","A","A","B","A",  "B","B","B", "A","C","C" , "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B"))

df$firstTrt = NA
df$firstTrt = ifelse(df$V1 == 1, df$T1, NA)

df$start <- NULL
df$start <- ifelse(df$V1 == 1 & df$T1 == df$T2 & df$R2 == "Response", df$V2, NA)
```

The end time for Dave would be 92 because he stopped responding to treatment A and was his R2 was "Disease" on his second visit (day 714). Angel would have no start time because they never saw a response on the first treatment given. Joe's end time would be 150 because he stopped seeing a response on visit 375 so the end time would be the same as start time. Lastly, Cara's end time would be 375 because we are assuming she was responding up until her death. Lastly, Tanya's end time would be 375 because that was the first response she saw with treatment B and technically up until visit 375 her treatment was B and then it changed.

I feel this is complicated to understand so I can answer questions in the comments. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many functions in R operate on all entries of a `vector` at once.
Since a `data.frame` is a `list` of `vectors` we can utilize that vectorization
without the need for a `loop` to operate on all rows of a `data.frame`.

I suggest the following steps to determine `start` and `end`:

1. Filter down to the 2 relevant rows for each patient:

   - first response starts
   - first response ends
2. Detect `start` using your `ifelse()` statement.
3. Detect `end` with a `case_when()` that detects “Disease” or “Death” in `R2`
   and checks that a valid `start` value exists. For “Disease” it returns V1, for “Death” V2.
4. Reformat results.

The code below uses the `dplyr` verb `mutate()` to apply the `ifelse()` and `case_when()`
statements as it is more concise and easier to read.

The code in your question initializes `df$firstTrt` and `df$start`, that is
not necessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  filter(R1 == "Disease" & R2 == "Response" & V1 == 1 |
           R1 == "Response" & R2 %in% c("Disease", "Death")) |>
  group_by(Patient) |>
  slice(1:2) |>
  mutate(
    start = ifelse(V1 == 1 & T1 == T2 & R2 == "Response", V2, NA),
    end = case_when(
      R2 == "Disease" & !is.na(lag(start)) ~ V1,
      R2 == "Death" & !is.na(lag(start)) ~ V2,
      TRUE ~ NA
    )
  ) |>
  fill(end, .direction =  "up") |>
  select(Patient, start, end) |>
  slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Groups:   Patient [5]
#>   Patient start   end
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Angel      NA    NA
#> 2 Cara      150   375
#> 3 Dave       92    92
#> 4 Joe       150   150
#> 5 Tanya     150   375
```

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for! I really thought a loop was the only thing that would help me. Thank you so much for all your help!